# Is there a way of forwarding 2 domains to a HTTPS address in 1 htaaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have both a .com and a .com.au address for the same domain. I have them both pointing to the same hosting in the DNS. But because of my current htaaccess file, they both become .com.au

I am new to editing these files and have tried using a few solutions I have found but none appear to be working I always end up at the .com.au address with https visible

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.domainname.com.au/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the original code I was using. If anyone has any idea on how to edit this file to redirect http://www.domainname.com.au to https://www.domainname.com.au and http://www.domainname.com to https://www.domainname.com that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteBase /
#http to https (two specific domains)
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (a\.com|a\.com\.au)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Replace `a\.com` and `a\.com\.au` with your actual domains in the `%{HTTP_HOST}` condition pattern above.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply,

I have tried this out and the .com is redirecting to the.com.au address instead of changing https, the .com.au is not changing either.

Have I updated it correctly?

    RewriteBase /
    #http to https (two specific domains)
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (mydomain.com|mydomain.com.au)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: @N.Dance Why did you remove `https://www.` part in your code? Use my code as it is. Try clearing your browser's cache if the issue persists.

Comment: I did not remove it. but the above appears to have turned it into a link.  the only line i chaged was this one RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (domain.com|domain.com.au)$ [NC]  and neither change to https and the.com and redirecting to the .com.au